# How to show and hide multiple divs as I click the respective button with only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I'm trying to show and hide divs as the user clicks the button.
I wanna change the image source of the button too, but my head is already exploding. So, one thing at time.

I know how to hide and show the divs one by one, but I'm struggling trying to automate the process.

Here's a screenshot of the page (mobile version):
[Here I am!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVRzi.png)

The buttons have two classes:

`class="button button_0"`
`class="button button_1"`
and so on

Here are the iD model of the divs:
`answer_0`
`answer_1`
and so on

The main.js:

```
const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const iconList = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
const div = document.querySelectorAll('.container__answer');
const imgArray = ["assets/images/icon-minus.svg", "assets/images/icon-plus.svg"];

//functions


function changeImgSource () {
    if (idIcon.src.match(imgArray[0])) {
        idIcon.src = imgArray[1];
    } else if (idIcon.src.match(imgArray[1])) {
        idIcon.src = imgArray[0];
    }
}

function showHide () {
    if (idAnswer.style.display === "none") {
        idAnswer.style.display = block;
    } else {
        idAnswer.style.display = none;
    }
}

function all () {
    showHide ();
    changeImgSource ();
}

//i dont know :,(

let count = 0;


//I'll change to "for". Just think it's easier to read as a js newbie.

while (count < buttonList.length) {
    const button = buttonList[count];
    const classButton = button.classList[1];
    const idIcon = `#icon_${classButton}`;
    const idAnswer =`#answer_${classButton}`;

    button.onclick = function () {
        showHide(idAnswer);
    }

    count++;
}
```

Here's the GitHub Project. Is a free FrontEnd Mentor challenge, so I don't think there's a problem sharing.
[GitHub Project](https://github.com/IgorGGuimaraes/fac-accordion)

As the Opera's console kept repeating the "idAnswer" was undefined, I tried to change the code's order. But it, at least alone, didn't help much.

At the end, Opera's inspector kept reapeating the message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'display')"

I've tried some fancier codes too, but I didn't understand much and didn't work at the end.

Comment: Please add enough of the relevant code here to create a [mre]. This would likely include HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a runnable example here on Stack Overflow. Note that all relevant code must be here on Stack Overflow, not just on GitHub or another site.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to not use IDs and instead use [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/queryselector). That way, it's extendable and reusable. This also leads you to be using classes to manage the show/hide rather than setting style properties directly (like style.display='block'). Here I am just coloring the cell, but you could easily change this to a show hide situation. Here's an example

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  let allBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block button')
  allBlocks.forEach(btn => {
    // first add an event listener to the buttons
    btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
      // deselect the currently selected one
      // we put in the ? in case it doesn't exist yet
document.querySelector('.block.active')?.classList.remove('active');
      // now activate the one I clicked on - e.target here represents the button clicked
      e.target.closest('.block').classList.add('active');
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='blocks'>
  <div class='block'>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
  <div class='block'>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```